# calculating probability for a maximum a posteriori hypothesis problem

Tags: probability, bayes-theorem

You are given a coin that may or may not be biased. Specifically, you have
three hypotheses about the coin:

```
H1 = "the coin has probability 1=2 of landing heads"
H2 = "the coin has probability 1=3 of landing heads"
H3 = "the coin has probability 2=3 of landing heads"
```

I am given that the priors are:

```
P(H1) = 1/3
P(H2) = 1/3
P(H3) = 1/3
```

I toss the one coin seven times and observe 5 heads.

I want to calculate P(D|H1), P(D|H2), P(D|H3) but I do not even know where to begin. Do I have to use the hypothesis given to calculate this? Or is there some other way of calculating such?

Where D is the observed event that we see 5 heads and two tails.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"Do I have to use the hypothesis given to calculate this?" Yes. $P(D|H1)$ means the probability of the event $D$ conditional on $H1$, so you obtain it by assuming $H1$ and calculating probability of $D$ under that assumption.

Comment: Ah I think I got it. So for P(D|H1) I got (1/128) is this correct?

Comment: Yes, that is correct if your definition of $D$ is such that the order of the heads and tails matters. On the other hand, if the order doesn't matter, the probability is higher (in this case, look up the binomial distribution). However, if your goal is to compute $P(H|D)$, it doesn't actually matter which of the aforementioned definitions for $D$ you use.